# Android SQLite error when inserting into table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I have 2 forms in seperate fragments that the user fills in and the data is saved to the SQLite database. I had no problem doing this with just one table, one form and one fragment but now I have added a second table(kindetails) into MyDBHelper class with another form and fragment class and that data is then saved to the second table(kindetails). When I fill in the form and click on "addKinButtonClicked" I get the following errors.

**Logcat**

```
02-23 16:40:36.891  20144-20144/com.androidbegin.absfragtabhost E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: kindetails
02-23 16:40:36.901  20144-20144/com.androidbegin.absfragtabhost E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting address1kin=jamaica emailkin=bobby@gmail.com address2kin=jamaica phonekin=0871234567 firstnamekin=bob surnamekin=marley youremailkin=bob@gmail.com
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: kindetails (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO kindetails(address1kin,emailkin,address2kin,phonekin,firstnamekin,surnamekin,youremailkin) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at com.androidbegin.absfragtabhost.MyDBHandler.addKinDetails(MyDBHandler.java:93)
        at com.androidbegin.absfragtabhost.FragmentTab4.addKinButtonClicked(FragmentTab4.java:97)
        at com.androidbegin.absfragtabhost.FragmentTab4$1.onClick(FragmentTab4.java:29)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MyDBHelper class**

```
package com.androidbegin.absfragtabhost;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "detailsDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_DETAILS = "details";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
public static final String COLUMN_SURNAME = "surname";
public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS1 = "address1";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS2 = "address2";

public static final String TABLE_KIN_DETAILS = "kindetails";
public static final String COLUMN_KIN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_KIN_YOUREMAIL = "youremailkin";
public static final String COLUMN_KIN_FIRSTNAME = "firstnamekin";
public static final String COLUMN_KIN_SURNAME = "surnamekin";
public static final String COLUMN_KIN_PHONE = "phonekin";
public static final String COLUMN_KIN_EMAIL = "emailkin";
public static final String COLUMN_KIN_ADDRESS1 = "address1kin";
public static final String COLUMN_KIN_ADDRESS2 = "address2kin";

// Pass database information along to superclass
public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DETAILS + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_SURNAME + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_ADDRESS1 + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_ADDRESS2 + " TEXT "
            + ");";
    String query2 = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_KIN_DETAILS + "("
            + COLUMN_KIN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_KIN_YOUREMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_KIN_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_KIN_SURNAME + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_KIN_PHONE + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_KIN_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_KIN_ADDRESS1 + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_KIN_ADDRESS2 + " TEXT "
            + ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.execSQL(query2);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DETAILS);
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_KIN_DETAILS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//Add a new row to the database
public void addDetails(Details details){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, details.getFirstname());
    values.put(COLUMN_SURNAME, details.getSurname());
    values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, details.getPhone());
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, details.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS1, details.getAddress1());
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS2, details.getAddress2());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_DETAILS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void addKinDetails(KinDetails kinDetails){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_KIN_YOUREMAIL, kinDetails.getyourEmailkin());
    values.put(COLUMN_KIN_FIRSTNAME, kinDetails.getFirstnamekin());
    values.put(COLUMN_KIN_SURNAME, kinDetails.getSurnamekin());
    values.put(COLUMN_KIN_PHONE, kinDetails.getPhonekin());
    values.put(COLUMN_KIN_EMAIL, kinDetails.getEmailkin());
    values.put(COLUMN_KIN_ADDRESS1, kinDetails.getAddress1kin());
    values.put(COLUMN_KIN_ADDRESS2, kinDetails.getAddress2kin());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_KIN_DETAILS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

}
```

**FragmentTab4 class**

```
package com.androidbegin.absfragtabhost;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class FragmentTab4 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab4, container, false);

    Button addKinButtonClicked = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addKinButtonClicked);
    addKinButtonClicked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            addKinButtonClicked(v);
        }
    });



    //setContentView(R.layout.fragment1);
    yourEmailKin = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourEmailKin);
    editYourEmailKin = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editYourEmailKin);

    firstNameKin = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.firstNameKin);
    editTextNameKin = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextNameKin);

    surNameKin = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.surNameKin);
    editTextSurnameKin = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextSurnameKin);

    mobileKin = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobileKin);
    editTextMobileKin = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextMobileKin);

    EmailKin = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EmailKin);
    editTextEmailKin = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailKin);

    address1Kin = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.address1Kin);
    editTextAddress1Kin = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress1Kin);

    address2kin = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.address2Kin);
    editTextAddress2Kin = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress2Kin);

    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity(), null, null, 1);

    return rootView;
}

TextView yourEmailKin;
EditText editYourEmailKin;

TextView firstNameKin;
EditText editTextNameKin;

TextView surNameKin;
EditText editTextSurnameKin;

TextView mobileKin;
EditText editTextMobileKin;

TextView EmailKin;
EditText editTextEmailKin;

TextView address1Kin;
EditText editTextAddress1Kin;

TextView address2kin;
EditText editTextAddress2Kin;

MyDBHandler dbHandler;



//Add details to the database
public void addKinButtonClicked(View view) {
    KinDetails kinDetails = new KinDetails("");
    kinDetails.setYourEmailkin(editYourEmailKin.getText().toString());
    kinDetails.setFirstnamekin(editTextNameKin.getText().toString());
    kinDetails.setSurnamekin(editTextSurnameKin.getText().toString());
    kinDetails.setPhonekin(editTextMobileKin.getText().toString());
    kinDetails.setEmailkin(editTextEmailKin.getText().toString());
    kinDetails.setAddress1kin(editTextAddress1Kin.getText().toString());
    kinDetails.setAddress2kin(editTextAddress2Kin.getText().toString());
    dbHandler.addKinDetails(kinDetails);
    //printDatabase();
}

}
```

**FragmentTab4 xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<!-- Users Email -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yourEmailKin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/kinyouremail"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editYourEmailKin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"/>


<!-- First name -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstNameKin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/kinfirstname"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNameKin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"/>


<!-- Surname -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/surNameKin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/kinsurname" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSurnameKin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>



<!-- mobile -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mobileKin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/kinphone" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextMobileKin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>



<!-- Email -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/EmailKin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/kinemail" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextEmailKin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>




<!-- Address1 -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address1Kin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/kinaddress1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextAddress1Kin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>




<!-- Address2 -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address2Kin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/kinaddress2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextAddress2Kin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>



<!-- Button -->

<Button android:id="@+id/addKinButtonClicked"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:onClick="addKinButtonClicked"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Uninstall your app so the old database gets removed and the helper `onCreate()` is run again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: Always something simple